# Log results in linear regression

Tags: r, regression, linear, logarithm

I am just starting working with regression in R. I used some variables and their logs as well in the same regression equation. Unexpectedly, the results show significance of both, variables and their logs. My question now is regarding the coefficients of these variables and their logs; can it happen that the variable has positive sign and its log has negative sign? If possible, which one to choose and interpret then?

Comment: Using variables and their logs in the same regression is very unusual in the first place. Is there any specific reason why you are doing it?

Comment: @Trivio I wouldn't say "very" unusual: it's scarcely different in spirit or approach than including a quadratic term in a regression.